# Can I configure MySQL so that newly added columns allow nulls by default?

Tags: mysql

Our developers frequently forget to specify that nulls are allowed when adding columns to existing tables. MySQL defaults to not allowing nulls if Null is not included when using the Alter Table command to add a column

Is there a way to configure MySQL so that new columns allow nulls unless Not Null is explicitly included with the alter table command?

We use PHPMyAdmin to alter tables so a method of making all newly added fields allow nulls through PHPMyAdmin would work.

Comment: Sorry to be snarky, but your question asks "Our developers consistently deliver defective software to production. Can we alter production processes to work around those developer defects?"  Whether or not it's possible to alter production processes, I hope you'll consider tightening up your software quality and release process.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's default behavior **is** allowing nulls by default on `alter table` commands. It probably has something to do with **PHPMyAdmin**.

```
mysql> desc foo;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id        | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| client_id | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| item_id   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table foo add (a char(1));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> desc foo;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id        | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| client_id | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| item_id   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| a         | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the DEFAULT NULL when creating the new column like:

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD COLUMN column VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
```